# Display lines instead of empty cells in html table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to display something like the following picture in the empty cells of an html table (I'm using Bootstrap 4.3.1)

[image]

**Source code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Expected result:**

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can use it if necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a gradient background combined with `:empty`

```css
td:empty {
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 0 3px,#000 0 6px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

An SVG if you want better rendering.

```css
td:empty {
  background:
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="2 0 2 3"><line x1="0" y1="5" x2="4" y2="-1" stroke="black"></line><line x1="2" y1="5" x2="6" y2="-1" stroke="black"></line></svg>') 0 0/8px 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `:empty`

```css
td:empty{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Lois</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```