# CSS input stripes effect : when the input empty

Tags: css

how to achieve this kind of effect(Stripes) when the input is empty.

[image]

Comment: this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990812/css-background-stripes-on-div

Comment: As far as applying the style only when empty, look at the [:placeholder-shown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown) CSS pseudoclass.  [Browser support info](https://caniuse.com/css-placeholder-shown).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65506820/8620333

Comment: you could use the attribute `required` for the input and style `input:invalid`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display lines instead of empty cells in html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65506755/display-lines-instead-of-empty-cells-in-html-table)